# How to trigger alerts in Prometheus when specific users login to OpenShift or Kubernetes?

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, prometheus

Using either kube_state_metrics or anything else I'd like to fire alerts in Prometheus AlertManager when a specific user logs in to the cluster, ie. kubeadmin or bob-smith.

Or in other words: where in Kubernetes or OpenShift is the logged-in state of a user tracked?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [auditing enabled](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/), especially if you have the mechanism for either scraping its output file, scraping the logs from the apiserver's container (if you have the audit output going to stdout), or a webhook to which the apiserver can post the audit events, the you can create an alert based on whichever of those mechanisms fits into your infrastructure

There are [quite a few apiserver flags](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/#options) which control the audit behavior